# React JSON problem, iterate for a each key of a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

***NOte***: I have updated this question on 21/05/2021. pls answer to this question,

**Data**

{
"_id": "3fad6024-3226-451b-9e81-1c544aaaebf7",
"name": "ank retailer part 2",
"aboutUs": "part 2 updated",
"retailerLanguage": [
{
"languageID": "20b4772c-2470-4eaa-bc0c-61429700781cd",
"language": {
"name": "Koreandddd",
"__typename": "language"
}
},
{
"languageID": "8f04da56-0f53-4694-b6dc-0eb5a3aa2990",
"language": {
"name": "Mandarin",
"__typename": "language"
}
}
],
"termsAndConditions": "agreed"
}

I have tried this:

```
const tifOptionsES6 = Object.keys(d).map(key => {
  return Edited "{key}" to {d[key]} 
})
```

but unable to iterate for array key

**Expected Output**

```
Edited "name" to ank retailer part 2 
Edited "aboutUs" to part 2 updated
Edited "retailerLanguage" to Koreandddd , Mandarin
Edited "termsAndConditions" to part 2 agreed
```

and also check for not null

Comment: what's the expected output?

Comment: @bel3atar  ->  Edited "name" to ank retailer part 2
Edited "aboutUs" to part 2 updated
Edited "agents" to  89add463-7cb7-442a-b705-405e03f7e86a , 1c98d888-6c43-463c-b7ed-79ea8736125f

Comment: The question is very vague, can you try to write more about what is the problem.

Comment: @jaybhatt now pls read the question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = {"_id":"3fad6024-3226-451b-9e81-1c544aaaebf7","name":"ank retailer part 2","agents":[{"agentID":"89add463-7cb7-442a-b705-405e03f7e86a"},{"agentID":"1c98d888-6c43-463c-b7ed-79ea8736125f"}],"aboutUs":"part 2 updated","agentTitle":null,"retailerLanguage":[{"languageID":"8f04da56-0f53-4694-b6dc-0eb5a3aa2990"},{"languageID":"20b4772c-2470-4eaa-bc0c-61429700781c"},{"languageID":"3176fef7-9088-43c0-a8f3-47af51eb6e12"}],"retailerIndustries":[{"industryName":"Laundry"},{"industryName":"Aircon"}],"termsAndConditions":"not agreed"}

const mappings = {
  agents: 'agentID',
  retailerLanguage: 'languageID',
  retailerIndustries: 'industryName'
}

const printInputKey = key => {
  const item = input[key]
  return typeof item === 'string' 
    ? item 
    : item.map(x => x[mappings[key]])
}
const output = ['name', 'aboutUs', 'agents', 'retailerLanguage', 'retailerIndustries']
  .map(key => 
    `Edited "${key}" to ${printInputKey(key)}`
  ).join(' ')

console.log(output)
```

Comment: thats awesome  @bel3atar,  how do i do for "retailerLanguage" ?

Comment: you need to test for `typeof d[key]` just like I did in the `printInputKey` function, if the type is an array then you handle it differently

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {"_id":"3fad6024-3226-451b-9e81-1c544aaaebf7","name":"ank retailer part 2","agents":[{"agentID":"89add463-7cb7-442a-b705-405e03f7e86a"},{"agentID":"1c98d888-6c43-463c-b7ed-79ea8736125f"}],"aboutUs":"part 2 updated","agentTitle":null,"retailerLanguage":[{"languageID":"8f04da56-0f53-4694-b6dc-0eb5a3aa2990"},{"languageID":"20b4772c-2470-4eaa-bc0c-61429700781c"},{"languageID":"3176fef7-9088-43c0-a8f3-47af51eb6e12"}],"retailerIndustries":[{"industryName":"Laundry"},{"industryName":"Aircon"}],"termsAndConditions":"not agreed"};
var exclusions = ["termsAndConditions"];

function deflateJSON(data) {
    if (typeof(data) == 'string')
        return data;
    else {
        let result = Object.values(data).filter((x) => x != null);
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = deflateJSON(result[i]);
        }
        return result.join(",");
    }

}

function processData(data, exclusions) {
    let p = [];
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(d)) {
        (value != null  && !exclusions.includes(key)) && p.push(`Edited "${key}" to ${ deflateJSON(value) }`)
    }
    return p.join("\n");

}
console.log(processData(data,exclusions));
```

Comment: Thank you, Can you pls answer to this question. Thanks in advance  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67534422/compare-two-json-objects-and-just-return-another-json-object-with-only-the-chang